# MySQL database update via form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

[image]I'm making a form with which I can put something in my MySQL database, but for some reason it isn't working. When I try to submit the form it runs the else statement which means I get *error* Can someone tell me what I'm doning wrong???

I have two files the first one is the form:

```
        <html>
<body>

<form name="form4" method="post" action="incident_submit.php">

<table>
<tr>
<td>Gebruiker</td>
<td>:</td>
<td>
<?php /* Include de pagina waar je config file staat */

include 'dbconnectie.php'; /* INCLUDE CONNECTION */

$query = $query = "SELECT naam FROM gebruikers"; /* YOUR QUERY */
$uitvoeren = mysqli_query($connectie,$query); /* EXECUTE QUERY */

echo "<select name='naam' id='naam'>";

while($rij = mysqli_fetch_array($uitvoeren)){ /* FETCH ARRAY */
/* De data in de dropdown zetten */
$naam=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$rij['naam']);
echo "<option value='$naam'>".$naam."</option>";
}
/* De dropdown beëindigen */
echo '</select>';
?>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hardwaretypen</td>
<td>:</td>
<td>
<select name="typen" id="typen"> <?php
$query2 = "SELECT typen FROM hardware_typen"; /* YOUR SECOND QUERY */
/* Query uitvoeren */
$uitvoeren2 = mysqli_query($connectie,$query2); /* EXECUTE SECOND QUERY */
/* Begin van dropdown
While voor data in de dropdown */
while($rij2 = mysqli_fetch_array($uitvoeren2)) { /* SECOND FETCH */
$typen=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$rij2['typen']); /* ESCAPE STRINGS */
/* De data in de dropdown zetten */
echo "<option value='$typen'>".$typen."</option>";
}
/* De dropdown beëindigen */
echo '</select>';
?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Melding</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="melding" type="text" id="melding"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Incident melden"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The second file:

```
        <?php

include('dbconnectie.php');

/* Get values from form */
$naam=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['naam']); /* PRACTICE ESCAPING STRINGS BEFORE USING THEM INTO A QUERY */
$typen=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['typen']);
$melding=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['melding']);

/* Insert data into mysql */
$sql="INSERT INTO incidenten(naam, typen, melding) VALUES ('$naam', '$typen', '$melding')";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); /* EXECUTE QUERY */

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Uw melding is verwerkt in het systeem.";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='gebruikerpagina.html'>Terug naar de startpagina</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysqli_close($connectie);
?>
```

My MySQL table gebruikers:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gebruikers` (
  `naam` text NOT NULL,
  `wachtwoord` text NOT NULL,
  `level` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `gebruikers` (`naam`, `wachtwoord`, `level`) VALUES
('niek', 'P@password1', 1),
('Hansie', 'Hansie1', 3);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to remove echo '<select>'; in both select

Comment: The error I get is that it won't save the data in my MySQL database.        Removing the echo'<select>'; didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Summary of Answer:

- Converted code from deprecated **MySQL** to **MySQLi**.
- Too many include function of **dbconnectie.php** where-in you can just use it once in a page.
- Tried to clean the html table.
- Used *mysqli_real_escape_string* function on variables to prevent some of the SQL injections.
- Removed unnecessary and excessive `<select>`
- Missing `>`
- And **importantly**! Missing **value tags** in your `<option>`

I have included explanations quoted in /* */ inside the code I have provided for further reference.

**dbconnectie.php**:

```
<?php

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","helpdesk_middenpolder");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

Your **form**:

```
<html>
<body>

<form name="form4" method="post" action="incident_submit.php">

<table>
<tr>
<td>Gebruiker</td>
<td>:</td>
<td>
<?php /* Include de pagina waar je config file staat */

include 'dbconnectie.php'; /* INCLUDE CONNECTION */

$uitvoeren = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM gebruikers"); /* YOUR QUERY */

echo "<select name='naam' id='naam'>";

while($rij = mysqli_fetch_array($uitvoeren)){ /* FETCH ARRAY */
/* De data in de dropdown zetten */
$naam=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$rij['naam']);
echo "<option value='$naam'>".$naam."</option>";
}
/* De dropdown beëindigen */
echo '</select>';
?>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hardwaretypen</td>
<td>:</td>

<td>
<select name="typen" id="typen">
<?php
$query2 = "SELECT typen FROM hardware_typen"; /* YOUR SECOND QUERY */
/* Query uitvoeren */
$uitvoeren2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2); /* EXECUTE SECOND QUERY */
/* Begin van dropdown
While voor data in de dropdown */
while($rij2 = mysqli_fetch_array($uitvoeren2)) { /* SECOND FETCH */
$typen=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$rij2['typen']); /* ESCAPE STRINGS */
/* De data in de dropdown zetten */
echo "<option value='$typen'>".$typen."</option>";
}
/* De dropdown beëindigen */
echo '</select>';
?>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>Melding</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="melding" type="text" id="melding"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Incident melden"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**incident_submit.php**:

```
<?php

include('dbconnectie.php');

/* Get values from form */
$naam=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['naam']); /* PRACTICE ESCAPING STRINGS BEFORE USING THEM INTO A QUERY */
$typen=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['typen']);
$melding=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['melding']);

/* Insert data into mysql */
$sql="INSERT INTO incidenten (naam, typen, melding) VALUES ('$naam', '$typen', '$melding')";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); /* EXECUTE QUERY */

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Uw melding is verwerkt in het systeem.";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='gebruikerpagina.html'>Terug naar de startpagina</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

// close connection 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I still get two different errors when I load the form:    Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\wamp\www\Helpdeskapplicatie\incident_melden.php on line 16           Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\Helpdeskapplicatie\incident_melden.php on line 20

Comment: @niekerd - Check your table gebruikers in your database. Does it have a naam column? Or does level column has a '3' value on it? Check also your level column, is it in a numerical type (int, float, etc.) or in a text type (varchar,text, etc.)?

Comment: @niekerd - if it's an int, then change the query. I've updated the answer. Your first query should look like this: $query = "SELECT naam FROM gebruikers WHERE level=3";

Comment: Is it really necessary for level=3? If not, then remove the where clause. OR, try to change the structure of your gebruikers table by making the level column from int(1) to int(11).

Comment: removed it but it still gives me these errors: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\wamp\www\Helpdeskapplicatie\incident_melden.php on line 16                     Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\Helpdeskapplicatie\incident_melden.php on line 20

Comment: Can you edit your post and include in it the table structure of your gebruikers table.

Comment: I updated my post and also included my gebruikers table

Comment: @niekerd - try to change your level column from int(1) to int(11)

Comment: Try changing your query from $query = "SELECT naam FROM gebruikers WHERE level=3"; to $query = "SELECT * FROM gebruikers";

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\wamp\www\Helpdeskapplicatie\incident_melden.php on line 15   Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\Helpdeskapplicatie\incident_melden.php on line 19       still have the errors for some reason

Comment: @niekerd - while looking for the cause of the bug, study this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @niekerd - the only cause of the bug that I'm seeing is the gebruikers table. Can you show me the print screen of your table? Is the gebruikers table in the helpdesk_middenpolder database?

Comment: Added the print screen of my table to the question

Comment: @niekerd if my answer still finds helpful, you can give it an upvote

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$sql="INSERT INTO {$tbl_name}(naam, typen, melding)VALUES('$naam', '$typen', '$melding')";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); // will display the error
```

When adding - or die (mysql_error()) it will display errors related to MySql engine (such as wrong username & password, typos , etc)

Comment: The error I get is this: Unknown column 'typen' in 'field list'

Comment: excellent! that means the the field 'typen' is not exists. check your mysql table to see why is it happening.

Comment: Now I get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''incidenten'(naam, typen, melding)VALUES('Hansie', 'Desktop', 'Gaat niet aan.')' at line 1

Comment: you have a syntax error. 'incidenten'(na .. remove the ' sign

Comment: Remove the inverted commas around 'incidenten'

Answer (score 0):

add name and Id to select for both naam and typen

```
echo '<select id="naam" name="naam">';//add name and id
//While voor data in de dropdown
while($rij = mysql_fetch_assoc($uitvoeren)) {
//De data in de dropdown zetten
echo '<option>'.$rij['naam'].'</option>';
}
//De dropdown beëindigen
echo '</select>';
```

and here

```
echo '<select id="typen" name="typen">';//add name and id
//While voor data in de dropdown
while($rij = mysql_fetch_assoc($uitvoeren)) {
//De data in de dropdown zetten
echo '<option>'.$rij['typen'].'</option>';
}
//De dropdown beëindigen
echo '</select>';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your form select to (**you have one more select in select**) Also no need to include file twice:-

```
<td>
<?php //Include de pagina waar je config file staat
include 'dbconnectie.php';
//Query
$query = "SELECT naam FROM gebruikers WHERE level='3'";
//Query uitvoeren
$uitvoeren = mysql_query($query);
?>
<select name="naam" id="naam" >
<?php while($rij = mysql_fetch_assoc($uitvoeren)) {?>
  <option value="<?php echo $rij['naam'];?>"><?php echo $rij['naam'];?></option>
<?php }?>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td>Hardwaretypen</td>
<td>:</td>
<td>
<?php $query = "SELECT typen FROM hardware_typen";
//Query uitvoeren
$uitvoeren = mysql_query($query);?>
<select name="typen" id="typen">
<?php while($rij = mysql_fetch_assoc($uitvoeren)) {?>
<option value="<?php echo $rij['typen'];?>"><?php echo $rij['typen'];?></option>
<?php }?>
</select></td>
```

and then insert query to :-

```
$sql="INSERT INTO incidenten (naam, typen, melding)VALUES('$naam', '$typen', '$melding')";
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''incidenten'(naam, typen, melding)VALUES('Hansie', 'Laptop', 'geen internet ')' at line 1

Comment: try to put table name directly like updated answer or same way you going